# Нужен совет, как лучше реализовать модель статей и файлов на django?

Tags: python, django

Всем добрый день. Пришел за советом.
Как лучше реализовать модели статьи и файлы, где будут одинаковые поля, но файлы будут лишь отличаться тем, что там будет на 2-3 поля больше. Категории те же самые.

Может сделать одну модель, но не заполнять некоторые поля, которые предназначены для файла? Но тут возникает то, что в файлах больше полей - мешать будут.

А фильтровать потом как их отдельно? Скорее только по категориям.

А возможно ли сделать так, чтоб допустим при добавлении с админки, или с сайта, мы могли выбрать будет это файл или статья? И для тех в последствии выводить нужные поля?

Если есть пример такой штуки, скиньте пожалуйста для изучения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй наследование моделей. Определи базовую модель, в которой будут указаны общие для этих моделей поля. А затем в модели отвечающей за статьи и файлы опиши собственные поля

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        

class FileModel(BaseModel):
    file_field = ...
    ...


class Article(BaseModel):
    article_field = ...
```

фильтровать сможешь как обычно

```
   Article.objects.filter(...)
   FileModel.objects.filter(...)
```

затем при редактировании, соответственно, сможешь передавать какой-то доп. параметр, который будет отвечать за то, какая именно модель редактируется(либо проверять наличие определенных полей) и тогда подставлять ту форму, которая тебе нужна, например в файле  forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
```

и тогда во view, который отвечает за редактирование

```
def file_or_article_edit_view(request, object_type='file'):
    available_form_classes = {
       'file': FileForm,
       'article': ArticleForm,
    }
    form_class = available_form_classes.get[object_type]
    form = form_class(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
          form.save()
    
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {
        'form': 'form',
    })
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! А как им резольверы прописать? У меня два вьюхи для обработки категории, но если смотреть главную страницу, вьюха берет не тот резольвер (ибо они очень похоже, но не от той модели)   path('p/<slug:cat_slug>/', PostCategory.as_view(), name='categories'),
    path('f/<slug:cat_slug>/', FileCategory.as_view(), name='categories'),

Comment: ты дай им разные имена, а то они обе называются одинаково `name='categories'`

Comment: Да, вы правы. Вчера порылся, немного разобрался. В админке можно как-то сделать, чтоб тоже была одна форма на материалы и файлы и если заполнены поля от файлов, то моделька сейвилась в файлы? Я так понял, что ваш код под вью, это и есть оно, но я не шарю как в админке такое же сотворить, чтоб всё в одном месте добавлять. И кстати, самое важное - огромная благодарность вам за вашу человеческую помощь. Знал бы, где тут ещё репу ставить, хоть 1000 поставил бы в плюс.

Comment: мне кажется самый простой вариант это с помощью `.js` на странице проверять какие поля заполнены и в зависимости от этого менять у формы аттрибут action. Но он, на мой взгляд, отдает неким читерством что-ли)

Comment: У меня настолько читерство, что я ещё bs4 прикрутил для себя, кое-что парсю. Делаю просто проект, хочу сделать на английском, и облегчить его работу в плане загрузки или добавления статей. Просто уже есть один сайт на php на 5к хостов, но он на CMS, а тут питон и более чем понятный Django на нем, поэтому хотел узнать то, что ещё не описано в документации)))